# Create a macro that copies specific data in columns and pastes the data into different columns in a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro which selects specific columns in one workbook and then in another workbook according to the column the data is pasted, as the columns are different in both workbooks.

I am able to select in Workbook 1; column C and in Workbook 2 column Z3 and paste the values; but for this I have to highlight all the values in Workbook 1: Column C and then run the macro.

I don't know how to create a macro which does this on click- automatically and also for multiple columns. Below I have included the code that works when the values are selected,

```
Range("C47:C581").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Workbook2.xls").Activate
Range("Z3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("Workbook1.xlsm").Activate
```

I am not able to include images so i will explain below using examples. 
Below is what Workbook 1 Sheet 1.

```
Column A    Column B    Column C    Column 
1             1           11          5555
2             2           22          4444
2             3           33          3333
```

I want to create a macro that finds the number of cells in Column A (not including the heading) and pastes them into Workbook 2 Column C . The code above in my description only works for a specified range; i have tried the NumberOfCells but i am not sure why this doesn't work

Comment: Change `Selection.Copy` to `workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).copy`

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this; it appears to select the entire column and doesn't paste any values. I also receive an error message to say that the copy and paste area are not the same..do you know why this is?

Comment: I'm new to VB so i'm sort of running and recording macros and then changing the code...Yes it works if i select the same number of cells. I have another macro which finds the range but the range can change so i was trying to work out how it can find, select and paste the same values

Comment: Yes, i mean the range, the below code works but this range can change;                                                                         Range("C47:C581").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Sheet2.xls").Activate
    Range("Z3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("Sheet1.xlsm").Activate

Comment: Do the columns that you want copied in both workbooks share same heading? Also, macros are cool but copy pasting is easy. Why macro?

Comment: I have edited my question :) ... they are not the same headings but i don't want to copy the headings just the values in those columns

Comment: I see but it's still unclear what you want XD See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636714/copy-specific-cells-from-different-rows-to-one-row-on-a-separate-sheet-move-to) on how to be really specific...

Comment: I have edited my question, i hope that this is clearer :)

Comment: So you want to copy workbook1 column A into workbook2 column C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code and your explanation don't match so this is a guess to what you want. **Backup your files first.**

This takes column A from workbook1, sheet1 (excluding heading) and copies it to workbook2, sheet1, column C starting at cell C2.

```
Sub SO()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsm").WorkSheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsm").WorkSheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Copy

ws2.Range("C2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```