# Copy specific cells from different rows to one row on a separate sheet & move to new row based on value in original

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large dataset (around 96,000 entries) representing courses run by different education providers. In total there are around 5,500 different course providers.

Instead of each row containing all the courses offered by a single provider, each course has its own row with a column identifying the providers id (i.e. for one provider id, there are 750 rows representing various bits of information relating to each course). An example of the data is provided here:

```
   +-----------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| COURSE_ID | PROVIDER_ID |        LAD_ID         |         PROVIDER_COURSE_TITLE         |                    COURSE_SUMMARY                    | PROVIDER_COURSE_ID |      COURSE_URL       |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|  53072591 |      300015 |                       | Functional English 1                  | English Entry 3 and Level 1                          |                    | http://www.asfc.ac.uk |
|  53072593 |      300015 |                       | Functional English 2                  | Literacy level 1 and 2                               |                    | http://www.asfc.ac.uk |
|  53072595 |      300015 |                       | Functional Maths 1                    | "Anyone who wants to improve their maths skills .    |                    | http://www.asfc.ac.uk |
|  53728417 |      300015 |                       | HND in Creative Media Production      | This course is aimed at those with a passion         |                    | http://www.asfc.ac.uk |
|  53887498 |      300017 | 60133600              | Floristry NCFE Creative Craft Level 1 | This is an assessed course                           | AADE1215XA         | http://www.esc.ac.uk/ |
|  53887499 |      300017 | 60132322              | Floristry NCFE Creative Craft Level 2 | This course follows on from the NCFE Level 1         | AADE1218XA         | http://www.esc.ac.uk/ |
|  53887500 |      300017 | Z0002105              | Upholstery                            | This course will give you                            | AADE1X37XA         | http://www.esc.ac.uk/ |
|  53887501 |      300017 | Z0002105              | Upholstery                            | The aim of this course is to give the inexperienced  | AADE1X38XA         | http://www.esc.ac.uk/ |
+-----------+-------------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

I would like to create a new sheet formatted so that each row represents a unique provider (e.g. Provider i.d 300015 on row 2, 300017 on row 3) followed by each individual course that provider runs on the same row. It would be ideal if I could select only the fields PROVIDER_COURSE_TITLE, COURSE_SUMMARY, COURSE_URL for each course from the original sheet to copy across to the new sheet rather than the whole row.

Ultimately I'm looking for a table that looks like a bit like this

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| PROVIDER_ID |    COURSE_TITLE1     |       COURSE_SUMMARY1       |      COURSE_URL1      |    COURSE_TITLE2     |    COURSE_SUMMARY2     |      COURSE_URL2      |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|      300015 | Functional English 1 | English Entry 3 and Level 1 | http://www.asfc.ac.uk | Functional English 2 | Literacy level 1 and 2 | http://www.asfc.ac.uk |
+-------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Essentially therefore I need a macro that searches the PROVIDER_ID column and identifies a unique provider id, and subsequently copies that across to a new sheet. Then it identifies all rows with that Provider_ID, and copies the PROVIDER_COURSE_TITLE, COURSE_SUMMARY and COURSE_URL from each of those rows, and pastes them in to the new worksheet on the singular row for that provider_id.

I have spent a whole day trying to get my head around this, and had a couple of other people look at this, and we can't figure out the loops, the find next blank cell commands, and rules to move on to the next PROVIDER_ID needed.

Comment: Does every course have a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the routine that will do this for you. Place this routine in a standard code module:

```
Sub Courses()
    Dim c&, i&, j&, k&, s$, v, w
    v = [A1].CurrentRegion
    For i = 2 To UBound(v)
        If InStr(s, "|" & v(i, 2)) = 0 Then s = s & "|" & v(i, 2)
    Next
    ReDim w(1 To 1 + UBound(Split(s, "|")), 1 To 10000)
    w(1, 1) = "PROVIDER_ID"
    s = ""
    k = 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(v)
        If s <> v(i, 2) Then
            c = 1
            j = 1
            k = k + 1
            s = v(i, 2)
            w(k, 1) = v(i, 2)
        End If
        w(k, j + 1) = Trim$(v(i, 4)): If Len(w(1, j + 1)) = 0 Then w(1, j + 1) = "COURSE_TITLE" & c
        w(k, j + 2) = Trim$(v(i, 5)): If Len(w(1, j + 2)) = 0 Then w(1, j + 2) = "COURSE_SUMMARY" & c
        w(k, j + 3) = Trim$(v(i, 7)): If Len(w(1, j + 3)) = 0 Then w(1, j + 3) = "COURSE_URL" & c
        j = j + 3
        c = c + 1
    Next
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    [A1].Resize(UBound(w, 1), UBound(w, 2)) = w
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Then on the worksheet where you want the work done, press ALT-F8 to open the Macro Dialog.

Run the Courses macro.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - will be checking this out this week. Really appreciate your help folks.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rngSrc As Range, rw As Range
    Dim dictR As Object, dictC As Object, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim pid, rL As Long, cD As Range

    Set dictR = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dictC = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rngSrc = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Reformatted")

    'first empty row...
    rL = shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each rw In rngSrc.Rows
        pid = Trim(rw.Cells(2).Value)

        If Not dictR.exists(pid) Then
            dictR.Add pid, rL  'tracking row
            dictC.Add pid, 2  'tracking column
            shtDest.Cells(rL, 1).Value = pid
            rL = rL + 1
        End If

        Set cD = shtDest.Cells(dictR(pid), dictC(pid))
        cD.Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(Trim(rw.Cells(4).Value), _
                                      Trim(rw.Cells(5).Value), _
                                      Trim(rw.Cells(7).Value))

        dictC(pid) = dictC(pid) + 3 'increment columns

    Next rw

End Sub
```